# Underlining Hyperlinks - Text-decoration vs. Border-bottom and Browser Inconsistencies

Tags: css

I'm not a big fan of the default text-decoration.  I ususally set it to "none" then do a "border-bottom: 1px dotted somecolor" on 'a' and a "border-bottom: 1px solid someothercolor" on 'a:hover'

I've noticed something recently that I don't think was happening before.  Even with padding-bottom on the text's

container set to 0, there's too much vertical space between the bottom of the letters and my border-bottom.

What's odder is that Chrome still seems to behave nicely and respect my 0 padding, but Firefox and IE appear to be adding about 4 or 5 pixels of vertical space.

When I temporarily revert to "text-decoration: underline" I still see too much space.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Can you post an example, perhaps a jsFiddle?

Comment: This may depend on font face, line height, padding settings, and other factors. Please provide more information.

Comment: (OP here) Hmmm.  When I tried to replicate the problem at jsFiddle, it worked fine.  I looked at the CSS on my site and just don't see anything obviously wrong.  I've got line-height set to 1.6em, but that doesn't break things at jsFiddle; neither does vertical-align:baseline.  As best as I can tell, all relevant paddings and margins are set to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to bet the culprit is `inline-block` as a display setting. See the difference (in Firefox) at http://jsfiddle.net/s8FYS/6/.

**EDIT**: Some further investigation reveals that `inline` Firefox (looking in Firebug) sets the `height` to `auto` which ends up less than the actual `line-height`, whereas `inline-block` calculates the `height` (since it is now acting like a `block`) equal to `line-height` * `font-size`, which pushes the `border` down.

You can "compensate" for it by setting the `height` (in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8FYS/12/), a `1.35em` worked with my default `font-size` of `16px`), but I'm not sure that doing such would necessarily compensate correctly at all times.

Comment: Yup, setting display to inline-block and height to 18px worked for me.  Border-bottom is appearing exactly where I want it to in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.  Thanks!

Comment: @user249493--just curious: did you test how that looks if someone has their browser set to scale their font height (not scaling the whole page)? I would think that a fixed height of 18px could see your border being gapped again (at say a 10px font) or in the middle of some cut off text (at say a 24px font). Most likely some type of `em` unit would be better for setting the height, that way if the user does have a font scaling, then the border should shift.

Comment: Dang! I had a feeling I was in trouble using px instead of em.  You're right - when font is scaled (either up or down), the border gap is wrong.  1.4em seems to be about right.  Lets me scale down to 10px default browser font size and at least up to 26px.  Looks fine in Firefox; need to test the others.

Answer (score 0):

Change line-height, for example:

> a{   line-height:1em; }